# How to start with stem?

Tags: python, tor, stem

I'm newbie in stem (Tor framework in python). I have windows 10 64 bit with python27 installed and stem library and Tor browser.
When I want to start my first code as below:

```
import sys

from stem.connection import connect

if __name__ == '__main__':
  controller = connect()

  if not controller:
    sys.exit(1)  # unable to get a connection

  print 'Tor is running version %s' % controller.get_version()
  controller.close()
```

I get this error:
Unable to connect to tor. Are you sure it's running?
[image]
Please help me what must I do.

Comment: The error asks you : "Are you sure it's running?" What is your answer ?

Comment: Exactly my question is here. What must I run? tor.exe? tor browser? or what?

Comment: One very interesting link is the Tor documentation : https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en

Comment: I hope that my question will be useful to solve this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651889/selenium-webdriver-tor-as-proxy-with-stem

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Tor not just the Tor Browser. I'm unsure if that is possible for Windows or not, I've never done it. I've set it up on an Ubuntu machine and it's pretty simple. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/setting-up-tor-for-use-with-stem this post seems useful to you also this should be useful to https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en